# GAE: Routes vs standard

Tags: python, google-app-engine, routes

In the last days I saw a lot of codes, like GAE Boilerplate, and almost all are using Routes to manage the page calls. And I'm wondering why? The official examples always uses the "normal" method:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/lang', ChangeLanguage)], debug=True)
```

but now I discovered this alternatives:

```
from webapp2_extras.routes import RedirectRoute

RedirectRoute('/lang/<lang>', ChangeLanguage, name='lang', strict_slash=True),
RedirectRoute('/', MainPage, name='home', strict_slash=True)
```

In the first case, I'm using parameters to pass my vars on the request (like `/lang?hl=en_US`) and in the second I must pass it as a path (like `/lang/en_US`).

But why use one method or the other? Is there any advantage?

Also, I notice that with the first method my forms can be called, in the get and put methods, e.g., `/register`, but with the routes, a get call for the same works, but when a post is done, it only works if the form action is `/register/` (whith the last slash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the primary features `webapp2` introduced over the original `webapp` is precisely the extension of functionality the Route class provides.

The documentation gives a pretty good explanation of what it attempts to achieve:

> webapp2 introduces a routing mechanism that extends the webapp model to provide additional features:
>
> - URI building: the registered routes can be built when needed, avoiding hardcoded URIs in the app code and templates. If you change the route definition in a compatible way during development, all places that use that route will continue to point to the correct URI. This is less error prone and easier to maintain.
> - Keyword arguments: handlers can receive keyword arguments from the matched URIs. This is easier to use and also more maintanable than positional arguments.
> - Nested routes: routes can be extended to match more than the request path. We will see below a route class that can also match domains and subdomains.
>
> [Source](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#extended-routes)

Bottom line, they're a more powerful version of routing, providing more features for the programmer.

---

As per your specific parameter question, you don't have to pass `lang` any specific way. In the first case, `lang` would be available as part of `request.GET`, in the second, as a positional argument to your request handler's method that matches the request method (`GET`, `POST`).

The difference is largely that in the case of `/lang?hl=en_US`, the argument is technically optional. Your request will still be matched with the handler even when the argument is absent, therefore you have to verify that `request.GET` contains data.

In the second case, `/lang/en_US`, the route is only matched, and thus the handler is only called when there's something to match in place of `<lang>`.

---

As per the slashes issue, you're using the `strict_slash` in your routes. [more here](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html?highlight=strict_slash)

Comment: Thank you, @Tomasz. I've read the links. Just 2 notes: in some cases it seems that can be good to use (and check) if a param has past on the request. E.g., in `lang?hl=en_US` I throw the message "Bad param" if I don't found it. With routes is launching a 404 error. Second, according to the strict_slash docs, a call to `/register` will redirect to `/register/`. Then, why the POST to `/register` fails? But finally, which is the difference between call `/register` or `/register/`, i.e., why people uses strict_slash?

Comment: @Eagle Correct, nothing wrong with either `lang?hl=en_US` or `/lang/en_US` - it's up to you which makes more sense for your particular case.

Comment: @Eagle As for the `POST` failing, (while you're not exactly clear what is and isn't working), the effect of strict_slash` is to issue a response with code `301` (redirect) when the requested URL is missing a trailing slash when one is expected or vice versa. Issuing redirection for `POST` is not a pattern I'd expect to see anywhere, as you should've already redirected the browser to the proper URL with the initial `GET`. This is why I believe the `webapp2.RedirectHandler` (part of webapp2's implementation of redirection) is not even implementing a `POST` handler.

Comment: @Eagle As for why you'd use `strict_slash` in general - to enforce a convention. This is a cosmetic convention, mind you. There's nothing special about ending your URLs with a slash or not. Not in the grand scheme of things anyway. It's simply a matter of what you want your URLs to look like.

Comment: Great last comments, @Tomasz, thank you very much. Has a lot of sense.